# Translating PHPMyAdmin MySQL connection configuration to JDBC

Tags: java, php, mysql, jdbc, blowfish

I have PHPMyAdmin connecting to a remote MySQL server, using those parameters:

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'ba17c1ec07d65003';
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '*remoteServer*:3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = '*user*';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '*password*';
```

I'm trying to connect to this MySQL server in Java, neither of those work:

```
final String url ="jdbc:mysql://*remoteServer*:3306/*user*";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "*user*", "*password*");
```

and, with ":3306" removed :

```
final String url ="jdbc:mysql://*remoteServer*/*user*";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "*user*", "*password*");
```

I'm getting this error:

```
SQLException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
The driver has not received any packets from the server.
SQLState:     08S01
VendorError:  0
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    ...
```

I think it comes from the "blowfish_secret" (which is just a random cookie) and "auth_type"="cookie" not being accounted for in Java.

How do I fix this?

Also, do I need to tell MySQL that he has to accept to talk to the jdbc driver? (if yes, I'm screwed, I don't have access to the MySQL config files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

blowfish_secret and auth_type are used only as part of the phpmyadmin software, they have nothing to do with a mysql connection.

Do you have firewalls allowing access to MySQL from the machine running java and do you have grants set up to access that user from that specific host?

Comment: Thanks!
I think the grants are ok: the machine running PHPMyAdmin is also running java, and PHPMyAdmin has no problem connecting to MySQL. Do you think PHPMyAdmin maintains the connection with that user all the time, event when I'm not logged onto it?

Comment: PHP Apps are not like java, the connection is established on every request. If you are connecting on the same machine with the same user/pass combination, then it should work. You may want to look at what the config options for phpMyAdmin mean here: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/Documentation.html#setup

Comment: Okay. So the problem seems to be elsewhere. Maybe some bad jdbc driver, connectivity issue on the java side, or some configuration in MySQL. Anyway, I think exporting the database and installing it on the front server will do just fine. Thanks for the assistance!